# Me Da un error al querer Compilar

Tags: java, compilar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código...

y este es el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y así sea que cambie el nombre de mi archivo.java a Punto.java me sale el mismo error.

Comment: De forma general cada clase pública debe ir en un archivo diferente. Lo que puedes hacer es quitar el modificador de acceso `public` a la clase Punto.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Bro,  no había pensado en eso. Si me sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Estás creando 2 clases públicas en un mismo archivo. Deberían ir en archivos separados; por ejemplo:

Punto.java
PruebaPunto.java

Espero haberte ayudado